# Код не хочет работать как надо PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Я написал код, в котором есть checkbox и pushbutton. Я попробовал сделать так, что при нажатии на checkbox окно получало флаг "QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint". Но после того как я уберу галочку оно уже не должно быть поверх всех окон.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(649, 237)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 0, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 90, 371, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.checkBox.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CLOSE"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "On the top of all windows"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) 

        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.ontop)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myClose)

    def ontop(self):
        if self.checkBox.isChecked():
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) 
            self.close()
            self.show()
        else:
            self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) 
            self.close()
            self.show()

    def myClose(self):
        self.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Зачем закрывать окно `self.close()`? Разве не `self.hide()`? Кст, а зачем нужен `myClose()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю переписать код через [setWindowFlag](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setWindowFlag).

Его второй параметр позволит включать или отключать флаг: `void QWidget::setWindowFlag(Qt::WindowType flag, bool on = true)`

Пример:

```
    def ontop(self):
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint, self.checkBox.isChecked())
        self.hide()
        self.show()
```

Весь код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(649, 237)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 0, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 90, 371, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.checkBox.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CLOSE"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "On the top of all windows"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.ontop)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myClose)

    def ontop(self):
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint, self.checkBox.isChecked())
        self.hide()
        self.show()

    def myClose(self):
        self.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

Обратите внимание, что сигнал

> void QCheckBox::stateChanged(int state)
>
> испускается всякий раз, когда изменяется состояние флажка, то есть всякий раз, когда пользователь проверяет или снимает его.

поэтому нет необходимости использовать `self.checkBox.isChecked()`

Да и использование `self.hide()`, а тем более `self.close()` - излишнее.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(649, 237)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 0, 81, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 90, 371, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.checkBox.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CLOSE"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "On the top of all windows"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.ontop)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myClose)

    def ontop(self, state):
        if state:
            self.setWindowFlags(
                QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint        
                | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint         
                | QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint  
            )  
        else:
            self.setWindowFlags(
                QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint       
                | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint         
                | QtCore.Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint  
            )
            
        self.show()

    def myClose(self):
        self.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]